# Filter in Azure Data Factory for white spaces

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to do a filter when a value contains just white spaces, but it does not work, I can get right data if the filter is different to white spaces, look:

**Works:**
trim(ZIPCODE)!=''

**Does not work (i need this):**
trim(ZIPCODE)==''

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#trim)" is to Remove leading and trailing whitespace from a string, and return the updated string.

You can use "[replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#replace)" --> Replace a substring with the specified string, and return the updated string.

### Example:

I have an array with values. `["hi","bye","cool","yep"]`

First, when there are no white spaces.

[image: ["hi","bye","cool","yep"]]

**Condition:** `@equals(replace(item(),' ',''),item())`

[image]

[image]

Next, when values have spaces in them `["hi","bye ","co ol","yep"]`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works